# Error in send variable Stimulsoft

Tags: stimulsoft

i use Stimulsoft for my project however this problam stop my project

my code:

```
string cn1 = @"data source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\Report.mrt;integrated security=True;connect timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;";
       stiReport1.Load("Report.mrt");
       stiReport1.Dictionary.Databases.Add(new Stimulsoft.Report.Dictionary.StiSqlDatabase("Connection11", cn1));
       stiReport1.Dictionary.Variables["Variable1"].Value =textBox1.Text;
       stiReport1.Render(false);
       this.stiViewerControl1.Report = stiReport1;
       this.stiViewerControl1.Refresh();
```

when i run that and fill textbox and submit :
Invalid column name 'اهواز'.

please help me

Comment: Did you try to change the name of the column?

Comment: Your problem is due to your design in the "Report.mrt" file. you are using incorrect column name in it's design.

Answer (score 0):

check `DataSource` columns name in `StiReport` Designer